# IList<T> member list in c#

Tags: c#, ilist

```
public class Session
{ 
    --private properties
     private string p1;
     private string p2;
     private string p3;
     .
     .
     .
     .
     private string p25;


     --public properties
      public string P1
      {
        get { return p1;}
        set{p1=value;}
      }
      .
      .
      .
      .
      public string P25
      {
       get { return p25;}
       set{p25=value;}
       }

     }
```

I have 25 public members in a class and when I make a IList of that class I get all the members .
I want only specific 5 members to be part of that IList Because when i convert that ilist to datatable i get 25 columns but i want only 5 columns in datatable.

```
IList<Session> listSessionAttachment = new List<Session>();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of your request (as well as your code asample which makes no sense at all), but if you have an `IList<T>`... well, you have an `IList<T>`. If you don't want `IList<T>` then you'll have to use something else.

Comment: Why are you using IList ? Can you please provide detail how you build IList ?

Comment: which 5 properties you want? any logic there ?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong; you are creating an `IList<Session>`, meaning it has all the properties of `Session` but you only want to access five?

Comment: It would also be useful to learn about automatically-implemented properties - I suspect you can cut down the amount of code in your Session class a lot. It would also be helpful to see how you're converting the `IList<Session>` to a `DataTable` - *that's* the place where you'd want to be selective about which properties to copy.

Comment: Actually I made session class and to add the session attachments of created session to database using datatable and put all the properties of attachments in session class itself. Rather than creating a datatable and binding the listview its easy to make a ilist of session class.

Comment: @ABeginner - Why didn't you put all the properties you need into a separate class and then have *one* property in the session of that type? For example `public class SessionAttachment { public string P1 { get; set; } public string P2 { get; set; } // ... }`, then in `Session`: `public SessionAttachment { get; set; }`. If you have that, then you don't need an `IList<Session>`, but an `IList<SessionAttachment>`. --- Btw, if you just use very simple properties like in the code you showed, you might want to look into [Auto-Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/bb384054.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude some properties from mapping to your database, you have to apply special attributes to these properties. Attributes depend on the tools you use to work with the database.
For example, if you use Entity Framework, you should set [NotMapped] attribute to proprety.

```
public class MyClass
{
    [NotMapped]
    public String Str1 { get; set; } // this property will not be a column in MyClass table
    public String Str2 { get; set; }
    public String Str3 { get; set; }
}
```

If you use DevExpress XPO - you should use [NonPersistent] attribute. 
I hope - this will solve your problem.